# Get record from dataset using Expression

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

I want to get records from a dataset using some Expression..!

This is my dataset [image]

This is my dataset I want to get regords between two dates based on punchDate.

Example : I want to get the records between `03-01-2012` to `25-01-2012` means it returns correct record.

Suppose I just give the input of dates like `03-12-2011` to `25-01-2012` means it returns error.

> Error : The source contains no DataRows;

I enclosed my code here:

```
protected void findbyexpression(string Expression)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        DataSet4TableAdapters.sp_getalltimesheetTableAdapter TA = new DataSet4TableAdapters.sp_getalltimesheetTableAdapter();
        DataSet4.sp_getalltimesheetDataTable DS = TA.GetData();
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        DT = DS[0].Table;
        DataRow[] foundRows;
        foundRows = DT.Select(Expression);
        if (DT.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", "<script language='javascript'>alert('No records found for request query');</script>", false);
        }
        else
        {
            panheader.Visible = true;
            dt1 = foundRows.CopyToDataTable();
            Session["TaskTable"] = dt1;
            grdvw.DataSource = Session["TaskTable"];
            grdvw.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e2)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", "<script language='javascript'>alert('" + e2.Message + "');</script>", false);
    }
}
```

and Expression is:

```
 string expression = "PunchDate >= '" + txtfromdate.Text + "' and PunchDate <= '" + txttodate.Text + "'";
            findbyexpression(expression);
```

please help me to get the records ..

Answer (score 0):

1. dataview = dataset.Tables[Table_Name].DefaultView;
2. dataview.RowFilter = "DATE>='" + startDate.ToShortDateString() + "' and DATE<='" + endDate.ToShortDateString()+ "'";
3. dataGridView1.DataSource = dataview;

Comment: Thanks for your Quick reply...Now i don't get the error . But No records found in dataview.

Comment: do you add the filter within dates you have in your dataset?? Mark it as answer if helped

Comment: I got the result using above expression but slight changes is that.    'string expression = "PunchDate >= #" + txtfromdate.Text + "# and PunchDate <= #" + txttodate.Text + "#";
            findbyexpression(expression);'   I just put hash instead of "'" in front of date string..

Answer (score 0):

your query is not selecting record properly. you can check this link to select date between ranges [Select date b/w ranges](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Date_Range_WHERE_Clause_Simplification). and use this condition.

```
 string expression = PunchDate < YourEndDate AND PunchDate  >= your StartDate.
```

- your query can be Sql Injected, try to use Parametrized queries.  [Parameterized query.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx)
- If possible try to rename all your variable to some meaningful Name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i got the result.